# React Binding issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need to bind api rsponse data to the textboxes:

```
                            <label htmlFor="jobTitle" className="form-label lbl">Job Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="jobTitle" name="jobTitle" className="form-input"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="Salary" className="form-label lbl">Salary:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Salary" name="Salary" className="form-input"/>
                        </div>
                        
                            document.getElementById('#jobTitle').value = response.data.jobTitle;
        document.querySelector('#Salary').value = response.data.salary;
        
        but it shows error:
        
        TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
```

want to know a method to access the textboxes to bind the data

Comment: That doesn't look like React code. Why are you using `document.getElementById` in React code? Why do you mix HTML and JavaScript? Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**getElementById** method dont accept id with '#' and **querySelector** method dont accept id without '#'.

Try this code:

```
document.getElementById('jobTitle').value = response.data.jobTitle;
document.getElementById('Salary').value = response.data.salary;
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#jobTitle').value = response.data.jobTitle;
document.querySelector('#Salary').value = response.data.salary;
```